# What do these orange lines in Object mode mean?

Tags: interface

What do those lines mean? And why they are inconsistent?
I think my vertices need to be merged?

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Blender highlights geometry edges so they're easier to see in x-ray mode. Don't worry about it being discontinuous.

Answer (score 3):

These are probably edges that are not part of any faces, for example if I extrude this vertex in *Edit* mode it creates an edge, here is what it gives in *Object* mode:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Run the 3d printing checks and fix whatever gets flagged.